# How to compile the function with FindRoot?

Tags: compile

How to compile this function or any function that uses lists and Part[] ?

```
f[x_?NumberQ] := FindRoot[x == Sin[t] - t, {t, 1}][[1, -1]];
```

Comment: `FindRoot` is not compilable: ``Compile`CompilerFunctions[] // Sort``

Comment: Also, when you call it like this, `FindRoot` is probably/hopefully sufficiently optimized that you won't gain anything by `Compile`ing.

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate of our "list of compilable functions" post. There is really not much more to say except that in basically all cases, you should not try to put `FindRoot` in a compiled function. There might be some rare exceptions but usually, it is a bad idea. In general, you should be concerned about the speed of the function you want to find the roots for. If you have a very complex expression that can be compiled, then this might be worth a shot.